# Dijkstra's algorithm in graph (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph

I need some help with the graph and Dijkstra's algorithm in python 3. I tested this code (look below) at one site and it says to me that the code works too long. Can anybody say me how to solve that or paste the example of code for this algorithm? I don't know how to speed up this code. I read many sites but l don't found normal examples...

P.S. Now l edit code in few places and tried to optimize it, nut it still too slow(

```
from collections import deque


class node: 

    def __init__(self, name, neighbors, distance, visited):
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.distance = distance
        self.visited = visited
        self.name = name
    
    def addNeighbor(self, neighbor_name, dist): # adding new neighbor and length to him
    
        if neighbor_name not in self.neighbors:
            self.neighbors.append(neighbor_name)
            self.distance.append(dist)

class graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.graphStructure = {} # vocabulary with information in format: node_name, [neighbors], [length to every neighbor], visited_status 
    
    
    def addNode(self, index): # adding new node to graph structure
    
        if self.graphStructure.get(index) is None:
            self.graphStructure[index] = node(index, [], [], False)


    def addConnection(self, node0_name, node1_name, length): # adding connection between 2 nodes
        n0 = self.graphStructure.get(node0_name)

        n0.addNeighbor(node1_name, length)

        n1 = self.graphStructure.get(node1_name)
        n1.addNeighbor(node0_name, length)
    
    def returnGraph(self): # printing graph nodes and connections

        print('')
        for i in range(len(self.graphStructure)):
            nodeInfo = self.graphStructure.get(i + 1)
            print('name =', nodeInfo.name, '  neighborns =', nodeInfo.neighbors, '           length to neighborns =', nodeInfo.distance)
        
    def bfs(self, index): # bfs method of searching (also used Dijkstra's algorithm)

        distanceToNodes = [float('inf')] * len(self.graphStructure)
        distanceToNodes[index - 1] = 0
        currentNode = self.graphStructure.get(index)
        queue = deque()
        
        for i in range(len(currentNode.neighbors)):
            n = currentNode.neighbors[i]
            distanceToNodes[n - 1] = currentNode.distance[i]
            queue.append(n)
        
        while len(queue) > 0: # creating queue and visition all nodes
            u = queue.popleft()
            node_u = self.graphStructure.get(u)
            node_u.visited = True

            for v in range(len(node_u.neighbors)):
                node_v = self.graphStructure.get(node_u.neighbors[v])
                distanceToNodes[node_u.neighbors[v] - 1] =  min(distanceToNodes[node_u.neighbors[v] - 1], distanceToNodes[u - 1] + node_u.distance[v]) # update minimal length to node
                if not node_v.visited:
                    queue.append(node_u.neighbors[v])
                    
        return distanceToNodes

def readInputToGraph(graph): # reading input data and write to graph datatbase
    node0, node1, length = map(int, input().split())

    graph.addNode(node0)
    graph.addNode(node1)
    graph.addConnection(node0, node1, length)


def main():
  newGraph = graph()
  countOfNodes, countOfPairs = map(int, input().split())

  if countOfPairs == 0:
      print('0')
      exit()

  for _ in range(countOfPairs): # reading input data for n(countOfPairs) rows
      readInputToGraph(newGraph)

  # newGraph.returnGraph() # printing information

  print(sum(newGraph.bfs(1))) # starting bfs from start position

  

main()
```

The input graph structure may look like this:

```
15 17
3 7 2
7 5 1
7 11 5
11 5 1
11 1 2
1 12 1
1 13 3
12 10 1
12 4 3
12 15 1
12 13 4
1 2 1
2 8 2
8 14 1
14 6 3
6 9 1
13 9 2
```

I'm only learning python so l think l could do something wrong(

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate to post on codereview.stackexchage.com instead?  For performance improvement.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to post this on codereview) I don't know this site before, thank you!

Comment: Great. Hope it's helpful.  You could write a high level description to detail your `questions` first.

Comment: @VolodymyrSafiyanyk Are you solving some competitive programming task? If you do, can you provide a link to the problem?

Comment: Yeah, l it's something like a task. It's a link to the site https://algotester.com/uk/ArchiveProblem/DisplayWithEditor/40794?tab=statements
The task is to find the sum of all minimal length's from the start node to all others

Comment: @VolodymyrSafiyanyk have you tried using a priority queue?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No l don't try to use it. I'll look for this) Thank you!

Comment: In competitive programming, priority queue is the most common way to implement Dijkstra, since normal queue implementation often fails the time limit

Comment: @AbhinavMathur But how about importing deque from collections in Python 3? As l know it can add or remove the object for O(1)

Comment: It's not about fast insertion/removal, priority queue allows you to process the paths with minimum weight first, improving the overall time complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm relies on retrieving the node with the shortest distance from the source in each iteration. Using your code as an example, the operation `u = queue.popleft()` MUST return the node that has the shortest distance from the source out of all nodes that are currently in the queue.

Looking at the documentation for `collections.deque`, I don't think the implementation guarantees that `popleft()` always returns the node with the lowest key. It simply returns the left most item in what is effectively a double linked list.

The run time of Dijkstra's algorithm (once you implement it correctly) almost entirely lies on the underlying data structure used to implement `queue`. I would suggest that you first revisit the correctness of your implementation, and once you can confirm that it is actually correct, then start experimenting with different data structures for `queue`.